# Why I can use AR,js in static html but not work in vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ar.js

I try to import AR.js with CDN in the web app build by vue CLI but not working(Can open camera but can't show AR item)

And I try to put code in static html and it can work, so I think the code is right(copy from AR.js getting start)

CDN I use, I put them at the end of head.

```html
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
```

My code in vue component.

```html
<template>
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-marker preset="hiro">
      <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="color: black;"></a-box>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</template>
```

Here is my console
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t8w3.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO! you can use Vue wrapper of AR.js. Find it out [here](https://github.com/mudin/vue-vr)

Comment: @TL.robin did you eventually find out why?